# Jquery UI timepicker slider and select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using Trent Richardsons Timepicker plugin: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/
As you can see in the demo, there is a method to switch the picker to a select format.

What I'm trying to achieve is to append the select method straight underneath the default slider - at the moment you can only have either the slider, or the select, not both at once.

I can see in the docs that you can create a custom control type to change the output of the select using $.timepicker.setDefaults({controlType:myControl}) - and then writing a custom function. Should I be somehow creating a new function that merges both the slider and select together?

Any tips at what I should be doing for this?